# remove sprite after CCBlink is done

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm strugling to find out how to clean the sprite after CCBlink, see that I don't want to make it invisible, I want to clear ir from memory

myAnimation = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:5 blinks:20];

thanks

Comment: sequence with callblock or callfunc that executes removefromparent...

Comment: just did it, worked fine

Comment: Similar to @LearnCocos2D, if you were using Kobold2D, you could just sequence with [CCRemoveFromParentAction action]